# SSRS Report Viewer Object reference not set to an instance of an object. after entering parameters

Tags: reporting-services, reportviewer

The report parameter bar shows up in this asp.net app via reportviewer but when I select view report all that renders is Object reference not set to an instance of an object where the report should render. Now I've looked all over for an explaination for this but nothing I've tried works. I'm just the report builder not the developer for the .Net program that holds the reportviewer. The reports render fine if you don't have to provide parameters. 
I've tried just about everything I've researched on and nothing works. I'm at a stand still.

Comment: If you have a helpful answer you should accept it. Click on checkmark under upvote/downvote counter. This will mark the question as "answered" and provide you with small reputation bonus. See [How do I ask](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) FAQ article.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chance is when a parameter is provided, the server-side code tries to retrieve data based on given parameter, and a bug within that code throws that exception. You can have the code-behind looked into to solve the issue. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks thats what it ended up being, just found out right after asking the question.